# Multi-Level Enum with Methods in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have 2 enums and 2 interfaces that I am trying to create in a specific way. The goal is to form a hierarchy where I can declare a list of methods that belong to one enum and a differnent list of values that belong to the combination of both enums.

For example: the methods declared within LevelOneOperations should belong to LevelOne only. Then methods declared witin LevelTwoOperations should belong to the combination of both together like A.1, A.2, A.3, etc.

```
 public enum LevelOne implements LevelOneOperations { 

     A {
          public boolean isValid(Request obj){ // logic }
          public void prepare(Request obj){ // logic }
     }, 
     B {
          public boolean isValid(Request obj){ // logic }
          public void prepare(Request obj){ // logic }
     } ... 
 }
```

---

```
 public enum LevelTwo implements LevelTwoOperations { 

     1 {
         public void process(LevelOne lev1, Request obj){ 
              switch(lev1){
              case A: // do something
              case B: // do something else
              case C: // do something else
              case D: // do the last thing
              } 
         }
     }, 
     2 {
         public void process(LevelOne lev1, Request obj){ // logic }
     } ... 
 }
```

---

```
 public interface LevelOneOperations {
      public boolean isValid(Request obj);
      public void prepare(Request obj);
 }

 public interface LevelTwoOperations {
      public void process(LevelOne lev1, Request obj);
 }
```

---

```
 public class myService {
      public void runProcess(Request obj){

          LevelOne l1 = LevelOne.valueOf(obj.getLevel1());
          LevelTwo l2 = LevelTwo.valueOf(obj.getLevel2());

          if(l1.isValid()){
             l1.prepare();
             l2.process(l1, obj);
          }
      }
 }
```

---

Is there a way I can create an enum hierarchy so that I don't need to use switch statements to control the flow of the application. I want to call the process like: LevelOne.LevelTwo.process(obj);

I need methods that apply to LevelOne for all types and some methods that apply to LevelOne.LevelTwo together so that I have a grouped enum like : A.1, A.2, A.3, B.1, B.2, B.3, C.1, C.2, C.3, D.1, D.2, D.3, etc. I am also trying to make it easy to expand upon in the future because these lists are only subsets of what we are expecting for this project.

Tomorrow if I want to add a new LevelOne like E or a new LevelTwo 4 then it shouldn't require a lot of rework to introduce and support a new constant like that. The internal business logic between each element is different. Even between sub levels like: A.1 and A.2 will be different because both enumerators are taken into consideration and effect the output of the process.

The only way that I can think of to implement any thing like this is through switch/case statements. Can you please let me know if there is another way that I can achieve this?

I don't want separate classes for each variation because it will be a lot of different service classes and this is for only one part of my application. Currently I would have 5 elements in my first enumerator and 2 elements in my second enumerator for a total of 10 combinations.

Comment: I suggest re-evaluating your design. A simpler approach would be defining these values as classes instead of enums, making `LevelOne` and `LevelTwo` simple interfaces. Instead of using the `switch` in `LevelTwo#process` call a method from the `LevelOne` interface. In you `main` method you can construct a list of classes which implement `LevelOne` and `LevelTwo`. In the future this list could be constructed based on a configuration file.

Comment: There is also a lot of overlap between the various elements. Common methods that apply to all. Using valueOf to find the implementation that I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) for this.

If you add a new `enum` to either of them, you're forced to implement all the new methods before the code will compile, unlike with a `switch` where you won't get compilation error if you miss one.

```
interface VerbAction {
    void run();
    void walk();
    void jump();
}
```

```
enum Verb {
    Run  { @Override void perform(VerbAction action) { action.run(); } },
    Walk { @Override void perform(VerbAction action) { action.walk(); } },
    Jump { @Override void perform(VerbAction action) { action.jump(); } };

    abstract void perform(VerbAction action);
}
```

```
enum Noun {
    Dog {
        @Override
        void perform(Verb verb) {
            verb.perform(new VerbAction() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Running dog
                }
                @Override
                public void walk() {
                    // Walking dog
                }
                @Override
                public void jump() {
                    // Jumping dog
                }
            });
        }
    },
    Cat {
        @Override
        void perform(Verb verb) {
            verb.perform(new VerbAction() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Running cat
                }
                @Override
                public void walk() {
                    // Walking cat
                }
                @Override
                public void jump() {
                    // Jumping cat
                }
            });
        }
    },
    Pony {
        @Override
        void perform(Verb verb) {
            verb.perform(new VerbAction() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Running pony
                }
                @Override
                public void walk() {
                    // Walking pony
                }
                @Override
                public void jump() {
                    // Jumping pony
                }
            });
        }
    };

    abstract void perform(Verb verb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this, and I don't need to implement the enum if I use default with Java 8 to give a default implementation. This helps though.